# RegEx in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, replace, sql-update, sql-server-2000

I have a large table with IT products nearly 3 million records.

In there for monitors/laptops screen size is described in various ways. Like...

```
17in
17.3-TFT
17.3TFT
12.1-inch
15"
```

I want above in format

```
17in
17.3in TFT
17.3in TFT
12.1in
15in
```

Please suggest me a update query with (RegEx preferred) since there can be combinations too..

My data is actually as follows

```
Hp EliteBook 8770w Core i5-3360m / 4GB 500GB 17.3-TFT Win7 Pro + Docking Station                   
Hp EliteBook 8770w Core i7-3630QM / 8GB 750GB 17.3TFT Blu-ray W8Pro/W7Pro + MON:23i                
10.1" Glos 1024x600 ledbubrsb2led Bottom Under Bottom Right                                         
10.1in Neoprene Sleeve Black (fits Up To 10.1-inch Mini Notebook)                                   
12.1" Matte 1024x768 Ccfl 1LCD For Lenovo                                                           
12.1-inch Antiglare Display
```

I could select them with following SQL.

```
select * from rprd   
where 
dsc like'%[0-9][0-9].[0-9]TFT%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as or
dsc like'%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][^A-Za-z0-9]TFT%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as or
dsc like'%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][^A-Za-z0-9]inch%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as or
dsc like'%[0-9][0-9].[0-9][^A-Za-z0-9]"%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as or
dsc like'%[0-9][0-9].[0-9]"%' collate sql_latin1_general_cp1_cs_as
```

I need a way to update those

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT substring(a, 0, LEN(a) - PatIndex('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(a)) + 2 ) + 
       CASE WHEN PatIndex('%TFT%', a) > 0 THEN 'in TFT'
            ELSE 'in'
       END    
FROM test;
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/710091/14)

Update:

```
UPDATE test SET a = (substring(a, 0, LEN(a) - PatIndex('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(a)) + 2 ) + 
           CASE WHEN PatIndex('%TFT%', a) > 0 THEN 'in TFT'
                ELSE 'in'
           END )
```

It is very complex not only one number. Maybe you can use (create condition for each type):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9]-TFT%', a) > 0 THEN replace(a, '-TFT', 'in TFT')
            WHEN PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9]TFT%', a) > 0 THEN replace(a, 'TFT', 'in TFT')
            WHEN PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9]-inch%', a) > 0 THEN replace(a, '-inch', 'in')
            WHEN PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9]-in%', a) > 0 THEN replace(a, '-in', 'in')
            WHEN PatIndex('%[0-9][0-9].[0-9]"%', a) > 0 THEN replace(a, '"', 'in')
            else a
       end
from test
```

[demo2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/28b99/2)

or maybe this can help: [Regular Expressions in T-SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4733/xp_pcre-Regular-Expressions-in-T-SQL) on SQL Server 2000

Comment: I faced issue on here

Comment: this is different question !